# Extracting multiple columns without loop

Tags: awk

I am writing an awk script that will take the output of grep and nicely format that into an HTML table.  The delimiter is the ":" character; the problem I'm running into is that that character can appear in the text as well.  So if I just use $1, $2, and $3 for the filename, line number, and comment respectively, I lose anything after the first : in the comment

Is there a way to say $1, $2, and then $3..NR without explicitly looping over the columns and concatenating them together?

Here's the script so far:

`

```
#!/usr/bin/awk

BEGIN {
    FS=":"

    print "<html><body>"
    print "<table>"
    print "<tr><td>File name</td><td>Line number</td><td>Comment</td></tr>"
}

{
    print "<tr><td>" $1 "</td><td>" $2 "</td><td>" $3 "</td></tr>"
}
END {
    print "</table>"
    print "</body></html>"

}`
```

And some sample input:

```
./mysql-connector-java-5.0.8/src/com/mysql/jdbc/BlobFromLocator.java:177:       // TODO: Make fetch size configurable
./mysql-connector-java-5.0.8/src/com/mysql/jdbc/CallableStatement.java:243:     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
./mysql-connector-java-5.0.8/src/com/mysql/jdbc/CallableStatement.java:836:     // TODO: Do this with less memory allocation
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BEGIN { FS=":"; OFS=":" }
{ name=$1; number=$2; $1=""; $2=""; comment=substr($0,3); }

Comment: This is clever. But you must be on a real Unix system or a BSD, for gawk I think you just need. `BEGIN { FS=":"; }` Even on oawk why set OFS?

Comment: I tried without modifying OFS at first, but the columns were changed to spaces in the comment field.

Answer (score 1):

```
{ print gensub(/^[^:]*:[^:]*:/,"","g") }
```

Comment: If you use awk with the command-line option `--re-interval`, you can use `/^([^:]*:){2}/`. More readable when you have more fields to delete.

Comment: You mean, "if you use `gawk` ..."

Comment: Yes, I mean `gawk`. (`awk` is often a symlink to `gawk`.)

Comment: Heh, interval expressions. I *would* use them if I could frob the feature from within the script. It's silly for it to be a CLI switch.

Comment: Modified slightly:

{name = $1; number = $2; comment = gensub(/^[^:]*:[^:]*:/, "", "g")}

Ohh, good old Regexps.

Comment: gensub didn't work on my unix box, though it did in cygwin.  Weird.